# What is the performance difference between gawk and ....?

Tags: c, perl, awk

This question has been discussed [here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291558/why-are-fact-checking-questions-not-welcome-on-stack-overflow) and my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29827706/3627607) give links to a test system to answer this.

---

The question often comes up about whether to use gawk or mawk or C or some other language due to performance so let's create a canonical question/answer for a trivial and typical awk program.

The result of this will be an answer that provides a comparison of the performance of different tools performing the basic text processing tasks of regexp matching and field splitting on a simple input file. If tool X is twice as fast as every other tool for this task then that is useful information. If all the tools take about the same amount of time then that is useful information too.

The way this will work is that over the next couple of days many people will contribute "answers" which are the programs to be tested and then one person (volunteers?) will test all of them on one platform (or a few people will test some subset on their platform so we can compare) and then all of the results will be collected into a single answer.

Given a 10 Million line input file created by this script:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=10000000;i++) print (i%5?"miss":"hit"),i,"  third\t \tfourth"}' > file

$ wc -l file
10000000 file

$ head -10 file
miss 1   third          fourth
miss 2   third          fourth
miss 3   third          fourth
miss 4   third          fourth
hit 5   third           fourth
miss 6   third          fourth
miss 7   third          fourth
miss 8   third          fourth
miss 9   third          fourth
hit 10   third          fourth
```

and given this awk script which prints the 4th then 1st then 3rd field of every line that starts with "hit" followed by an even number:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }
```

Here are the first 5 lines of expected output:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | head -5
fourth hit third
fourth hit third
fourth hit third
fourth hit third
fourth hit third
```

and here is the result when piped to a 2nd awk script to verify that the main script above is actually functioning exactly as intended:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file |
awk '!seen[$0]++{unq++;r=$0} END{print ((unq==1) && (seen[r]==1000000) && (r=="fourth hit third")) ? "PASS" : "FAIL"}'
PASS
```

Here are the timing results of the **3rd execution of** gawk 4.1.1 running in bash 4.3.33 on cygwin64:

```
$ time awk -f tst.awk file > /dev/null
real    0m4.711s
user    0m4.555s
sys     0m0.108s
```

Note the above is the 3rd execution to remove caching differences.

Can anyone provide the equivalent C, perl, python, whatever code to this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }
```

i.e. find THAT REGEXP on a line (we're not looking for some other solution that works around the need for a regexp), split the line at each series of contiguous white space and print the 4th, then 1st, then 3rd fields separated by a single blank char?

If so we can test them all on one platform to see/record the performance differences.

---

The code contributed so far:

AWK (can be tested against gawk, etc. but mawk, nawk and perhaps others will require [0-9] instead of [:digit:])

```
awk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file
```

PHP

```
php -R 'if(preg_match("/hit \d*0 /", $argn)){$f=preg_split("/\s+/", $argn); echo $f[3]." ".$f[0]." ".$f[2];}' < file
```

shell

```
egrep 'hit [[:digit:]]*0 ' file | awk '{print $4, $1, $3}'
grep --mmap -E "^hit [[:digit:]]*0 " file | awk '{print $4, $1, $3 }'
```

Ruby

```
$ cat tst.rb
File.open("file").readlines.each do |line|
  line.gsub(/(hit)\s[0-9]*0\s+(.*?)\s+(.*)/) { puts "#{$3} #{$1} #{$2}" }
end
$ ruby tst.rb
```

Perl

```
$ cat tst.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -nl
# A solution much like the Ruby one but with atomic grouping
print "$4 $1 $3" if /^(hit)(?>\s+)(\d*0)(?>\s+)((?>[^\s]+))(?>\s+)(?>([^\s]+))$/
$ perl tst.pl file
```

Python

```
none yet
```

C

```
none yet
```

Comment: Voted to close: One answer won't contain a solutions for each of C, Perl, Python and whatever. If you have a specific problem you need to solve, ask that. It's also asks for an unterminated list of answers, which is also disallowed.

Comment: I don't see the point of this. If performance *really* matters, pick C or C++. Otherwise, choose the one you're familiar with...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Choosing c/c++ if the execution time is neglible would be pointless though, there is speed of execution but there is also time to produce/write/compile(as c/c++ would need to be recompiled on different machines) the program that should be taken into account to choose the best solution for your needs !

Comment: This is an awful way of testing regex engines. It represents only a very very tiny of practical uses. You say you want to compare languages, but this excercise will not produce any data from which meaninful answers can be drawn.

Comment: I guess that `[0-9]` is a better choice than `[[:digit:]]` as it always means the same, regardless of locale.

Comment: The comparison of performance of various tools are also depend on support for optimization in those languages, the kind of data processed etc. The reason people assume C is faster is a lot these of tools are written in C. If, as you say, awk is highly optimized for text processing then it *could* be faster than  a trivial C program for processing a specific data. But that doesn't mean C is slower rather. And you don't even limit the languages/tools. Be surprised if this produces any 'canonical' answers (Tool X runs Y amount of time on my time for data D on my machine - what does it prove?).

Comment: It would make sense if you only limit the languages to text processing languages only. A general purpose language such as C or C++ can't be compared easily with awk etc. No one is going to write a C program to do a simple text processing anyway. Even if someone does, it can't simply prove awk is better than C or otherwise. That's how the text processing languges came into existence -- specialized ones.

Comment: If you understand why this question was closed, you'll understand I am trying to say.

Comment: I completely understand your point and obviously disagree that this would provide no useful information. We'll now go back to all just keeping asking and answering the same question, over and over with zero data and nothing at all to refer to. OK, sounds good, but I think I'll opt out...

Comment: Well, I am voting to re-open. But I still think the question too broad.

Comment: I'm be happy to reduce the scope. What do you suggest? If it's just the set of tools to be compared - I definitely want to keep gawk, mawk, C, and perl in there as those are the most common tools that I personally see get brought up in this context (but I mostly just look at awk/sed/grep questions) and obviously my opinion is it doesn't hurt to include the Ruby, PHP, bash, Python and/or whatever other scripts people want to add but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: This really *isn't* a good fit for SO. There are as many possible answers as there are languages. It makes *no* sense to post one answer per language; what does voting mean in that context? If we want canonical questions, I would recommend one per language, so that competing answers can actually be sorted by votes, and one answer per question can be accepted as correct.

Comment: Voting means that people liked the answer,that's all. This is not a competition - we're just trying to get one location where there is some kind of comparison of relative performance between multiple tools so that when people say things like "oh you should always use mawk or C or whatever for better performance" we have some basis to support or refute that.

Comment: @EdMorton are you allowed to use boost with c++ ?

Comment: But if there's a different answer for each language, which one will you choose as the accepted answer?

Comment: @Barmar the quickest one i would guess.

Comment: @JID I don't want to moderate which tools/languages people contribute so I guess you could use boost with c++ but I've never seen anyone suggest writing in that would be an alternative to an awk script so idk how useful that'd be. The intent of this thread is NOT to come up with the quickest way to perform the task.

Comment: @Barmar There will be one accepted answer and it will provide the comparison of all the tools. This is absolutely NOT about voting for the fastest solution. See paragraph 2 of my question, starting with `The result of this will be an answer that provides a comparison...`.

Comment: @EdMorton Doesn't look like anythings happening unless it gets reopened though :(

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm about to surrender and accept that the powers that be wont let us have any kind of reference point for when the questions repeatedly arise about relative execution speed. I keep hearing "it's too broad" with zero suggestions of how to make it less "broad" so I have absolutely no clue what the issue is and so I have no idea how to fix it and life's too short.... Thanks to all who contributed.

Comment: @meagar Simple question: and how do you suggest giving those 10 or 12 separate questions as reference when answering a comment like "This would be more effective in X or Y than Z" ? I thought SO was a Q/A base, wondering what is best suited for a kind of work sounds really in topic for me. Does it worth a talk on Meta SO ?

Comment: @Tensibai By all means

Comment: Maybe this could be migrated to a github project?  I wrote some C code using FILE pointers and was seeing timing of ~6.7s real time( 5 runs ).

Comment: @n0741337 sorry, Ive no idea what a github project is. Can you post the C code as an answer or edit my question to include your code (and timng for it plus the awk version for comparison on your machine)?

Comment: The way I wrote the code it feels grossly long to post inside your question, but I can try much later today.  My first guess about its speed is that it was I/O bound by fgets().  Fgets() code being faster for me to write then using fread() with large buffers and offsets and its own "line" management.

Comment: @meagar Asked on meta [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291558/why-are-fact-checking-questions-not-welcome-on-stack-overflow) for thoose wishing to participate

Answer (score 4):

Applying egrep before awk gives a great speedup:

```
paul@home ~ % wc -l file
    10000000 file
paul@home ~ % for i in {1..5}; do time egrep 'hit [[:digit:]]*0 ' file | awk '{print $4, $1, $3}' | wc -l ; done
    1000000
    egrep --color=auto 'hit [[:digit:]]*0 ' file  0.63s user 0.02s system 85% cpu 0.759 total
    awk '{print $4, $1, $3}'  0.70s user 0.01s system 93% cpu 0.760 total
    wc -l  0.00s user 0.02s system 2% cpu 0.760 total
    1000000
    egrep --color=auto 'hit [[:digit:]]*0 ' file  0.65s user 0.01s system 85% cpu 0.770 total
    awk '{print $4, $1, $3}'  0.71s user 0.01s system 93% cpu 0.771 total
    wc -l  0.00s user 0.02s system 2% cpu 0.771 total
    1000000
    egrep --color=auto 'hit [[:digit:]]*0 ' file  0.64s user 0.02s system 82% cpu 0.806 total
    awk '{print $4, $1, $3}'  0.73s user 0.01s system 91% cpu 0.807 total
    wc -l  0.02s user 0.00s system 2% cpu 0.807 total
    1000000
    egrep --color=auto 'hit [[:digit:]]*0 ' file  0.63s user 0.02s system 86% cpu 0.745 total
    awk '{print $4, $1, $3}'  0.69s user 0.01s system 92% cpu 0.746 total
    wc -l  0.00s user 0.02s system 2% cpu 0.746 total
    1000000
    egrep --color=auto 'hit [[:digit:]]*0 ' file  0.62s user 0.02s system 88% cpu 0.727 total
    awk '{print $4, $1, $3}'  0.67s user 0.01s system 93% cpu 0.728 total
    wc -l  0.00s user 0.02s system 2% cpu 0.728 total
```

versus:

```
paul@home ~ % for i in {1..5}; do time gawk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file > /dev/null; done
    gawk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file > /dev/null  2.46s user 0.04s system 97% cpu 2.548 total
    gawk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file > /dev/null  2.43s user 0.03s system 98% cpu 2.508 total
    gawk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file > /dev/null  2.40s user 0.04s system 98% cpu 2.489 total
    gawk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file > /dev/null  2.38s user 0.04s system 98% cpu 2.463 total
    gawk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file > /dev/null  2.39s user 0.03s system 98% cpu 2.465 total
```

'nawk' is even slower!

```
paul@home ~ % for i in {1..5}; do time nawk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file > /dev/null; done                                          
    nawk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file > /dev/null  6.05s user 0.06s system 92% cpu 6.606 total
    nawk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file > /dev/null  6.11s user 0.05s system 96% cpu 6.401 total
    nawk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file > /dev/null  5.78s user 0.04s system 97% cpu 5.975 total
    nawk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file > /dev/null  5.71s user 0.04s system 98% cpu 5.857 total
    nawk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file > /dev/null  6.34s user 0.05s system 93% cpu 6.855 total
```

Comment: Done - very little impact in the results. If you look at the first loop results you actually see the timing for awk and egrep separately (thanks zsh!) - running them together as a single command comes in at ~0.7s total on this box.

Comment: All these are directly copy-pasted from my terminal, with hostname changed and spaces added to get code markup. The different behavior comes from ZSH's `time` built-in, which is aware of pipes and (somehow) times each part individually. e.g.: `% time ./a | ./b | ./c` gives: 

`./a  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.008 total

./b  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 2.008 total

./c  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 3.008 total` where these scripts are just 'sleep 1', 'sleep 2', 'sleep 3'

Comment: Edited the grep example - i included wc -l to break the output up a bit too.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to give up on this question since this is the 2nd time it's been closed and the people closing it have provided no clue what it is they want to see changed to make it acceptable to them. Thanks for your contributions.

Answer (score 3):

- first Idea

  ```
  File.open("file").readlines.each do |line|
    line.gsub(/(hit)\s[0-9]*0\s+(.*?)\s+(.*)/) { puts "#{$3} #{$1} #{$2}" }
  end
  ```
- Second idea

  ```
  File.read("file").scan(/(hit)\s[[:digit:]]*0\s+(.*?)\s+(.*)/) { |f,s,t| puts "#{t} #{f} #{s}" }
  ```

Trying to get something able to compare answer I ended up creating a github repo [here](https://github.com/Tensibai/benchmark-awk-vs). Each push to this repo trigger a build on [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/Tensibai/benchmark-awk-vs) which compose a markdown file pushed in turn to the gh-pages branch to update a [web page](http://tensibai.github.io/benchmark-awk-vs/) with a view on the build results.

Anyone wishing to participate can fork the github repo, add tests and do a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) wich I'll merge asap if it does not break the others tests.

Comment: Yes I replaced the alias by [0-9]

Comment: Does Ruby support character classes like `[:digit:]` (or maybe `\d`)? I actually saw a massive degradation in the real and user awk timing output (it looked a LOT like your Ruby output) when I used `[0-9]` instead of `[:digit:]`.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow, I think I tried with \d with no significant difference, but I'll complete tomorrow

Comment: @EdMorton Answer updated with tests and a another idea really quicker.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to give up on this question since this is the 2nd time it's been closed and the people closing it have provided no clue what it is they want to see changed to make it acceptable to them. Thanks for your contributions.

Comment: @EdMorton You're welcome, do you think raising a talk about fact checking questions on Meta ?

Comment: I don't know what Meta is and to be honest just don't care to learn. I spend too much time on this site already :-)!

Comment: It's cool that you made the repo. One question, why does it say that the version of `nawk` used was `GNU Awk 3.1.8`?

Comment: @jena probably a bug in the setup, I haven't looked at it for while now

Comment: Got it. I'll try the tests myself when I have time with the langs I care about (mostly mawk and gawk). I will also try to write some `R` solution, just for fun. I can push it after, if it's gonna be any good.

Answer (score 3):

On OSX Yosemite

```
time bash -c 'grep --mmap -E "^hit [[:digit:]]*0 " file | awk '\''{print $4, $1, $3 }'\''' >/dev/null


real    0m5.741s
user    0m6.668s
sys     0m0.112s
```

Comment: As I understand it "time bash -c '...<cmd>...' " deliberately sub-shells to isolate the pipeline being timed and get stats for the entire execution. It has the disadvantage of also including the time to start up a new bash instance - probably neligible but depends on your system.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to give up on this question since this is the 2nd time it's been closed and the people closing it have provided no clue what it is they want to see changed to make it acceptable to them. Thanks for your contributions.

Comment: @paulw1128, As long as all test benchmarks are run in the same way, the constant overheard of bash doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Here comes an equivalent in PHP:

```
$ time php -R 'if(preg_match("/hit \d*0 /", $argn)){$f=preg_split("/\s+/", $argn); echo $f[3]." ".$f[0]." ".$f[2];}' < file > /dev/null
real    2m42.407s
user    2m41.934s
sys 0m0.355s
```

compared to your `awk`:

```
$ time awk -f tst.awk file > /dev/null
real    0m3.271s
user    0m3.165s
sys 0m0.104s
```

---

I tried a different approach in PHP where I iterate trough the file manually, this makes things a lot faster but I'm still not impressed:

*tst.php*

```
<?php

$fd=fopen('file', 'r');
while($line = fgets($fd)){
    if(preg_match("/hit \d*0 /", $line)){
        $f=preg_split("/\s+/", $line);
        echo $f[3]." ".$f[0]." ".$f[2]."\n";
    }
}
fclose($fd);
```

Results:

```
$ time php  tst.php > /dev/null 
real    0m27.354s
user    0m27.042s
sys 0m0.296s
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to give up on this question since this is the 2nd time it's been closed and the people closing it have provided no clue what it is they want to see changed to make it acceptable to them. Thanks for your contributions.

Answer (score 2):

`mawk` is slightly faster than `gawk`.

```
$ time bash -c 'mawk '\''/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }'\'' file | wc -l'
0

real    0m1.160s
user    0m0.484s
sys     0m0.052s

$ time bash -c 'gawk '\''/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }'\'' file | wc -l'
100000

real    0m1.648s
user    0m0.996s
sys     0m0.060s
```

(Only 1,000,000 lines in my input file. Best results of many displayed, though they were quite consistent.)

Comment: The mawk script is not be producing any output though so yes it should be significantly faster. Maybe it doesn't support character classes? Try changing `[:digit:]` to `0-9`.

Comment: I also didn't downvoted. But I still think your comments below the question were to harsh and addressed to the wrong recipient. (now it is looking better already, I just noticed that some were deleted). From my own experience I can say that the OP is always doing really helpful things on SO. Why not fixing the problem with your `mawk` command? It could be an upvote!

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I had a look yesterday from phone, seems I downvoted by error and didn't notice it. I can't remove now until you edit :(. Sorry again.

Comment: I upvoted to cancel the downvote. I'm sorry but I have to give up on this question since this is the 2nd time it's been closed and the people closing it have provided no clue what it is they want to see changed to make it acceptable to them. Thanks for your contributions.

Comment: @Ed Morton, I listed two policies your question violates in the first comment to your question, and they're not even the only two policies it violates.

Comment: @ikegami and the 2 policies are? You said `One answer won't contain a solutions for each of...` but yes it absolutely will as that is THE clearly stated outcome of this question. You also said `It's also asks for an unterminated list of answers` and no it does not, it clearly asks for scripts to be posted for a couple of days and then they would all be executed and the results summarized in one answer. So now what am I supposed to do? The people voting to close the question clearly aren't reading the question or if they are they don't understand it and I don't know how it could be more clear.

Comment: Re "and the 2 policies are?" Your question is too broad to be covered by each answer. Your question solicit answers which are partial lists and/or answers that form a list.

Comment: re "yes it absolutely will", You are clearly wrong, as you can see. None of the answers entirely covers your question.

Comment: @ikegami your posts in this thread are absolutely baffling. Either you STILL don't understand the purpose/structure of this question or you do understand it but are deliberately acting as if you don't. Either way, my conclusion once again is that I'm wasting my time trying to communicate with you.

Comment: Re "So now what am I supposed to do?", If you have question with which we can help ("I'm trying to get this working in C, but I'm having difficulty determining which steps are needed to perform the task.", "I'm trying to get this working in C, but I keep getting the following syntax error..."), ask it. Otherwise, you'll need to look elsewhere.

Comment: Re "Either you STILL don't understand the purpose of this question", The purpose of the question has no bearing on whether it violates the site's policies or not.